# username as controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am trying to develop a social network where people can visit mysite.com/username. I used the _remap function and I got it working, however it is not loading any of my other controllers. Can someone be of assistance please?

This is my default controller:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($username = NULL)
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if ($this->user_model->is_a_username($username)) {
            $data['title'] = $username;
            $data['main_content'] = 'users/profile_page';
            $this->load->view('shared/template',$data);
        } else {
            $this->home();
        }
    }

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
        show_404();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            $data['title'] = 'Carnect';
            $data['main_content'] = 'users/wall_page';
            $this->load->view('shared/template',$data); #if logged in show the user's wall
        } else {
            $data['title'] = 'Carnect';
            $data['main_content'] = 'welcome/index';
            $this->load->view('shared/template',$data); #if not logged in show the home page
        }       
    }
}
```

and this is my routes file:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';


$route['login'] = "auth/login";
$route['logout'] = "auth/logout";
$route['register'] = "auth/create_user";


/*$route['news'] = "news/index";
$route['politics'] = "politics/index";
$route['culture'] = "culture/index";
$route['messages'] = "messages/index";*/


$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "$1/$2";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "$1/$2/$3";
$route['(.*)'] = 'welcome/index/$1';
```

An example of one of the controllers that will not load..

```
session_start();

class News extends CI_Controller {

    function News()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index() {
        $data['title'] = 'Politics';
        $data['main_content'] = 'news/index';
        $this->load->view('shared/template',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is codeigniter still alive? Let it die already!

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project that has a similar requirement on those urls.

I did it by adding route like this:

```
$routes['news'] = 'news/index';
```

or

```
$routes['news'] = 'news';
```

which are exactly lines that you've commented.

Sadly, It isn't possible without those lines (at least I couldn't do it).

If your URL was: example.com/news/index, it would match the rule `$routes['(:any)/(:any)']`, but if it was `example.com/news`, it wouldn't match anything and go to your last rule.

CodeIgniter's Routing doesn't take real segments, but the uri segments shown in the url. Therefore, your url `example.com/news` would be interpreted as a `$username = news`.

You'd have to do this uri routing for each url which only has 1 uri segment. You'd want to make sure no user has the same username with your controllers or he/she can never visit the user page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a rule in `application/config/routes.php` file just add a following line

```
$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/index/$1";
```

You can access by using `http://example.com/username` if your have added .htaccess rule for removing `index.php` file from url or you can access like `http://example.com/index.php/username`

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that all of my other controllers still point go to the welcome/index function.

Comment: add this rule at the bottom of the file, please accept the answer if you find it useful